# Stepper motor going one step forward and one backward

Tags: driver, stepper-motor

I have DRV8825 driver wired like that:
[image: Wiring of stepper motor]

And I'm sending high and low signal in loop. Each 2 high signals motor moves one step. And it moves forward then next step backward. Yes, I've tried to switch wires - with surprising effect: motor still does the same

Comment: Try simply grounding the DIR input.

Comment: Check your motor connections. If you have the coils wired up wrong (i.e. you connect one wire from both coils to the same h-bridge output), this can happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have connected A1 and B1 to one coil and A2 and B2 to the second coil. Fixed problem by connecting 1a and 2a to one coil and 1b, 2b to second.

Comment: If this is the solution, it really isn't worded very clearly. Can you explain in more detail what was wrong?

Comment: 99% sure he's saying he connected A1 and B1 to one coil and A2 and B2 to the second coil... but props on editing the answer and actually making it worse! o_O

Comment: Czesc Kuba. That's not right then. Look at your diagram. A1/A2 to one coil, B1/B2 to the other.